# Is iterating over a Queue<T> guaranteed to be in queue order?

Tags: .net, collections, base-class-library

Is this guaranteed to always print `123`?

```
Queue<string> theQueue = new Queue<string>();
theQueue.Enqueue("1");
theQueue.Enqueue("2");
theQueue.Enqueue("3");
foreach(var str in theQueue)
{
    Console.Write(str);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

**Edit:**
I totally agree that a queue that enumerated in any other order would be obviously incorrect. That's why I asked the question. However, the abstract data type `queue` only makes guarantees about its `enqueue` and `dequeue` operations.

I'm looking for an answer that references documentation that guarantees this ordering in the .NET BCL.

Comment: I think most people are missing the point of your question. A queue is defined by how pushes and pops work. Iterating in this method is not defined in the normal definition of a queue

Comment: @bengoesboom [yes it is defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a9449ty.aspx), `Queue<T>.GetEnumerator()` has it's own MSDN page including example code that states that the `IEnumerable` that the `foreach` call uses will behave the same as `Peek()` and `Pop()`.

Comment: Did you read the MSDN page for `Queue<T>`? Seems like a good reference to me (how else would `Queue<T> b = new Queue<T>(a)` function?).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was referring to the abstract data type of "Queue", not a specific implementation

Comment: @bengoesboom what is this abstract data type that you speak of?  that's what Queue<T> is and it's GetEnumerator function is very well documented

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: that page shows an example in which things just happen to work out. But the documentation doesn't explicitly say, "Enumerating the queue will return items in the same order as if you had called Dequeue to empty the queue." So far as I can see, it's not in the contract.

Comment: @user7116: Assuming that `Queue<T>` is implemented as a circular buffer, `Queue<T> b = new Queue<T>(a)` could be implemented by copying the backing array and the `Head` and `Tail` indexes. There would be no need to iterate the items.

Comment: That said, [the implementation](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/CompMod/System/Collections/Generic/Queue@cs/1305376/Queue@cs) does what we would expect. But I don't see any explicit documentation.

Comment: @JimMischel I highlight the explicit documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is. A queue is a first-in, first-out collection and will be enumerated in order.

Comment: That seems intuitively correct to me, but is there any documentation to back you up?

Comment: The [Queue<T>.GetEnumerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a9449ty.aspx) page has much better example code.

Answer (score 2):

**Documentation Proof:**

Yes it is, from the [MSDN Documenation of GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a9449ty.aspx), emphisis mine

> Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the **first element** in the collection. At this position, Current is undefined. Therefore, you must call MoveNext to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current.
>
> Current returns the same object until MoveNext is called. MoveNext sets Current to the **next element.**

However that does not address what the **first element** in the collection will be. To answer that we need to go to the [description of Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) itself:

> Represents a first-in, first-out collection of objects.

Combining the two above statements we have the official code contract that *the first object returned from the Enumerator will be the **first element** in the collection* and the fact that *the first element in the collection will be the **first-in** object added to the collection* giving us our final output that iterating over a `Queue<T>` will always be in order.

---

As an aside, compare that to a `Dictionary`, the definition for [GetEnumerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c6ftx8b.aspx) states the same line about retrieving the first element first. However [Dictionary's description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) does include the explicit ordering of objects in the collection:

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

And that is why it is "legal" for a `Dictionary` not to return in insertion order.

Comment: Documentation for [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c6ftx8b.aspx) says exactly the same thing, and it's been shown that you can't count on the dictionary enumerating items in the order they're added. I'll grant that the implementation of `Queue<T>` works as one would expect (i.e. iterates in removal order), but I maintain that the behavior is just an implementation detail: nothing in the contract says that it *must* do so.

Comment: @JimMischel I have updated my answer incorporating my previous (deleted) comment. If you still feel that the documentation does not specify a code contract please let me know what I missed.

Comment: I understand your reasoning and I think it likely (as I always have) that they actually meant the documentation to specify a code contract. In my mind, the documentation leaves some wiggle room. I think it should explicitly state that items are iterated in removal order. But that's an issue I should take up with the documentation team.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iterating over a `Queue<T>` is guaranteed to be in the order items were added to it. This is the definition of a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) queue. From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx):

> Queues are useful for storing messages in the order they were received
>   for sequential processing. Objects stored in a Queue are inserted
>   at one end and removed from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MSDN page which describes GetEnumerator for Queue.  In summary (as other's have said) you're good to go.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a9449ty.aspx

Note that enumerating the queue this way does not change it's contents the way that looping over it calling Dequeue() would